# keyboard event should fire after filling text box

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I am working on keyboard events using j query. I have two text boxes one accepting first name and second one accepting last name. I want to alert first and the last name after filling the text box. I am using a(ascii code 65) key to fire event.
The problem here is event is firing when i am filling the text box. I don't want the interruption while entering name into the text box and i need to call the event after entering the text box. I am using ajax that connects c# in web forms.

Please help me with this.

This is my html code:

```
<div>
    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" style="width: 25%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                First Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Last Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" onkeyup="JqueryAjaxCall();" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is my Script:

```
   <script src="Scripts/jquery1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function JqueryAjaxCall() {
        var pageUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Test.aspx/jqueryAjaxCall") %>';
        var firstName = $("#<%= txtFirstName.ClientID %>").val();
        var lastName = $("#<%= txtLastName.ClientID %>").val();
        var parameter = { "firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: pageUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify(parameter),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $(document).keyup(function (event) {
                    if (event.which == 65)
                        alert(data.d);
                });
            },
            error: function (data, success, error) {
                alert("Error : " + error);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }


</script>
```

This is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;

public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }
[WebMethod]
public static string jqueryAjaxCall(string firstName, string lastName)
  {
    //Do coding staff.
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `onkeyup`, use `onchange` event.

onchange event will fire only on blur of the text box.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" onchange="JqueryAjaxCall();" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```